# Sort MySQL Query results by amount of recursion in foreign keys

Tags: mysql, recursion, sql-order-by, hierarchical-data

I have the following table:

```
+----+--------+
| id | parent |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 4      |
|  2 | 1      |
|  3 | NULL   |
|  4 | NULL   |
|  5 | 2      |
|  6 | 3      |
+----+--------+
```

I want this table to be ordered like this:

```
+----+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | parent |             Why it has to be ordered like this             |
+----+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|  5 | 2      | 5 has parent 2 has parent 1 has parent 4. So 3 rows above. |
|  2 | 1      | 2 has parent 1 has parent 4. So 2 rows above.              |
|  1 | 4      | 1 has parent 4. So 1 row above.                            |
|  6 | 3      | 6 has parent 3. So 1 row above.                            |
|  4 | NULL   | No parent. So 0 rows above.                                |
|  3 | NULL   | No parent. So 0 rows above.                                |
+----+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So I want to recursively count the ancestors of a row and sort on that. How can I do that?

Edit: I'm on MySQL version 5.7.21.

Comment: Why does this question have a -1 vote and 2 votes to close it? Please elaborate if you -1 vote, so I know what is wrong about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a recursive CTE, but you didn't list your mysql version and not all versions can do that, so here is something that should work even for older versions. This does the recursion itself with a temporary table and a while statement. The temporary table gets built with one record for each record in the main table, which holds the parent count data. First we do all records with no parent, then the query inside the while does all the records for the next generation. Note that the syntax may be a little bit off, I haven't done mysql for some time.

```
--Create temp table to hold the parent count data
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ParentCount (id int, pcount int);

--First create a pcount record with count zero for all records with no parent
insert into ParentCount (id, pcount) Select id, 0 from TestData where parent is null;

--If we don't have a parentcount set for every record, keep going
-- This will run once for every level of depth
While (Select COUNT(id) from TestData) <> (Select COUNT(id) from ParentCount) Begin

    --add a pcount record for all rows that don't have one yet, but whose
    -- parents do have one (ie the next generation)
    insert into ParentCount (id, pcount)
    Select T.id, P.pcount + 1 as newpcount
    from TestData T 
        inner join ParentCount P on P.id = T.parent
        left outer join ParentCount P2 on P2.id = T.id
    where P2.id is null;
End;

--final query
Select T.id, T.parent 
from TestData T 
  inner join Parents P on T.id = p.id 
order by P.pcount DESC, T.id ASC;
```

Comment: This actually seems to be a great solution, although there seems to be some overhead creating a temporary table. As I could easily update my MySQL instance to prerelease 8.0.4 I'd like to learn about how I could apply CTE's. Could you elaborate?

Comment: This is a link to an article talking about this. It uses Microsoft SQL syntax instead of mysql, but the theory is the same. It talks about different ways to use recursive CTEs for solving hierarchy problems. Your situation is the levels one. 
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2007/10/17/hierarchies-with-common-table-expressions/

Comment: A recursive CTE basically works very similar to what I did above - one query to handle the first generation (level), and then a second query that repeats to handle the next levels. It basically does all the WHILE and temp table stuff stuff behind the scenes, in the most optimised way for your query, but the guts of what happens is not that different.

Comment: Great content, thanks! I also found a nice article here: https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3634